# accelerated curved bounce

Tags: c++, curves

I'm trying to make a simple pong clone and want the ball to curve when the racket was moving on hit.
To test out curves I removed all the rackets and just have a ball bouncing around in a rectangle, curving in the positive Y direction.

I tried simulating gravity on the Y axis, but the outcome is weird.
The bigger the rectangle, the faster the velocity gets over time.
In a small rectangle, I lose velocity and the ball slows down.

I do the following:
On each tick I check if I should do a curve, if so, then I increase the curve force and add it to the Y velocity (curves only appear on Y)

```
if (this->DoCurve)
{
    //check if we don't exceed the maximum curve force
    if (this->CurveForce < this->CurveMaxForce)
        this->CurveForce += this->CurveIncrease*delta;

    //add curve force to Y
    this->Velocity += FVector(0.f, this->CurveForce, 0.f) * delta;
}
//move object to new location
SetLocation(this->CurrentLocation + this->Velocity * delta);
```

When I hit a wall, I want the curve to stop until I hit the next wall.

```
//if we are already curving, stop it and reset
if (this->DoCurve)
{
    //subtract the force we added to make it move normal again
    this->Velocity -= FVector(0.f, this->CurveForce, 0.f);
    this->CurveForce = 0;
}

this->DoCurve = !this->DoCurve;

//reflect
FVector ReflectedVelocity = (-2 * FVector::DotProduct(this->Velocity, Hit.Normal) * Hit.Normal + this->Velocity);
//ignore Z axis
ReflectedVelocity.Z = 0.f;

//ReflectedVelocity.Normalize(); // this makes the ball stuck in a wall
this->Velocity = ReflectedVelocity;
```

Basically I have no idea what I'm doing.

What I want:
When the ball hits a racket and it is moving I want the ball to move in a curve fast first, then slow down, like the racket gave it a boost.

My approach is very flawed, what would be the correct way?

Answer (score 1):

I would express the direction of the ball in an angle. The curve would increase that angle each timestep until a wall or a racket is hit.

A quick pseudo-code to give you an idea of what I mean:

```
Update(float deltatime)
{ 
    direction+=curveangle*deltatime;
    position.x += cos(direction)*velocity*deltatime;
    position.y += sin(direction)*velocity*deltatime;

    if(wall_is_hit)
    {
        curveangle=0;
        direction=new_wallbounce_direction();
    }
    if(racket_is_hit)
    {
        direction=new_direction();
        curveangle=new_curvature();
        velocity=new_velocity();
    }
}
```

This gives you a basic curve movement. If you want the curve to get slowly to a straight line, reduce the curveangle each step until it becomes 0 or if you want the curve to become more steep increase it to some defined maximum.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still learning coding soo this won't be a great answer but I hope I can help. If you set the velocity to increase after hitting a racket as a percentage instead of a flat rate and then set a max with a clause to return it to a normal speed after it hit's said max you might find what you're looking for.